# Prevent page refreshes updating a table in PHP - via <a> link and not a form

Tags: php, database, session, browser, hyperlink

I have some client code that uses 3 php pages to:

1. offer a long list of `<a>` links to the end user,
2. updates a database based on the link selected (and the passed params), and
3. confirms the update

Now, ignoring the fact that yes this isn't using a form, and yes, using a get to update a table is inherently wrong, there is an issue with multiple updates.

```
+----------+        +----------+        +----------+
| 1      \ |        | 2      \ |        | 3      \ |
|         \|        |         \|        |         \|
|          |  ----> |          | -----> |          |
| list.php |        | book.php |        | conf.php |
|          |        |          |        |          |
|          |        |          |        |          |
|          |        |          |        |          |
+----------+        +----------+        +----------+
                         |                          
                         |                          
                         v                          
                   +-----------+                    
                   | Update DB |                    
                   +-----------+
```

Due to the nature of the DB (it's FileMaker) the booking page (`book.php`) can take a while to update. Understandable impatience on the part of the users is causing them to refresh the page after clicking the link on `list.php`, and therefore multiple updates (in fact new records) in the table before getting to a `cons.php`.

What I can't get my head around is how to prevent this.

I've tried all sorts of approaches, (and the gotcha here is that I can't use forms!) and the one that I think would work best would be to pass a random key in from `list.php` in the params, and then start a session in `book.php` check that the key wasn't already in a session variable, and if it was ignore it, if it wasn't set it in the session variable, and then run the update. However, I can't seem to get it to work.

Any ideas oh great stackoverflow-ers?

UPDATE

Turns out code I wrote works locally on Apache but not on IIS !!?

list.php

```
<?php 
// list.php
session_start();

$key = time();

echo "<h2>List of Urls</h2>";
echo '<p><a href="book.php?key='.$key.'&booking=1">Book 1</a></p>';
echo '<p><a href="book.php?key='.$key.'&booking=2">Book 2</a></p>';
echo '<p><a href="book.php?key='.$key.'&booking=3">Book 3</a></p>';
echo '<p><a href="book.php?key='.$key.'&booking=4">Book 4</a></p>';

echo "<p>Time page rendered was $key</p>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

book.php

```
<?php 
// book.php
session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['key']) && $_SESSION['key'] == $_GET['key'] ) {
    header('Location: conf.php?error=doubleclicked');
} else {

    if( isset($_GET['key']) ) {
        $_SESSION['key'] = $_GET['key'];
    }

    header('Location: conf.php?key='.$_GET['key'].'&booking='.$_GET['booking']);
}

?>
```

conf.php

```
<?php
// conf.php 
session_start();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_GET);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given all the restrictions to do not fix it properly, I would go with AJAX and modal overlay on `list.php` page to prevent users clicking on `book.php` links unless they reload `list.php` first.

Something like:

```
$("a").on("click", function(){
    $("#dialog").show();
    $.ajax({url: $(this).attr('href')})
     .done(function() {window.location.href="conf.php"})
    return false;
});
```

with `#dialog` overlay saying something like "Please wait, don't reload."

Comment: :-) I'm glad you appreciate "all the restrictions to do not fix it properly", but the issue isn't the clicking of the links - it somehow seems to be refreshing the intermediate step - `book.php` takes so long, that they're refreshing book.php before it gets back its synchronous reply from FileMaker... so it makes another request to FileMaker... etc. etc.

Comment: Are you saying that `book.php` actually shows something to users, and not just redirect to `conf.php` ?

Comment: No, it updates the DB - but takes some time to do it - and then redirects.

Comment: So my advice is to do not open `book.php` page in the browser at all, so users have no chance to reload it. Send the `GET` request to `book.php` from javascript, catch response, and redirect them to `conf.php` from javascript.

Comment: I will look into that Alex - not entirely sure all the clients *are* running JS - Windows Exploder clients in a corporate environment. Will try and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Could you elaborate in which way your solution does not work on IIS? May be add `print_r($_SESSION)` to `conf.php`.

Comment: Alex, I managed to get a solution based on this approach to work. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery, you can try the following:

On top of list.php:

```
<style>
.loading
{
width:100%; 
height:100%; 
position:fixed; 
z-index:200;
background-image: url('http://  droppicture.com/images/loading/loading-03.jpg');
background-position: center top;
background-repeat:  repeat;
opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```
<div class="loading" style="display: none" id="loading" ></div>
```

At the bottom of the page:

```
$('#YOUR_LINK_ID').click(function(e){
 $('#loading').attr('style','display: block');
});
```